# Jenkins: Copying Artifact (directory) from one Job to another

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-plugins

in Jenkins, I have a job **downloadAgents** that is responsible of creating a folder and populating it with some files. Then the folder is saved as an artifact with the following folder structure

```
 dev\downloadAgents\target\dependency\ios
```

Then I need to copy the contents of the **ios** folder into the workspace of another job (into a specific folder).

I have added the **Copy artifacts from another project** step. And it does copy the artifacts, but it copies the full path

```
\dev\downloadIosAgents\target\dependency\ios
```

How can I tell jenkins to copy only one folder **ios** and everything that is inside it and, do not copy all folders that are before **ios**.

Also if there are already files in the destination folder, will it merge the 2 folders?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use regex for your copy (under "Artifacts to copy")-

dev\downloadAgents\target\dependency\ios***.*

** - all folders under ios

*.* - all file types

You can also specify the target directory, and you also have a flag for "Flatten directories". This will move all the files without the hierarchy of the folders (flat to your target directory)

Feel free to look at the plugin's home page: 
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Copy+Artifact+Plugin

Answer (score 0):

In CopyArtifacts plugin specify the pattern: `\dev\downloadIosAgents\target\dependency\ios\*.*` or `\dev\downloadIosAgents\target\dependency\ios\**` - I don't remember exactly.
That should do the job.